# NS3 installation on ubuntu ; build failed

Tags: installation

'm trying to install NS-3 on Ubuntu (using virtualbox), but when I want to do build.py this error occurs:

[build.py error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW4oB.png)

what should i do ? can anyone help me please
Thank you

Comment: Have you installed list of all packages from ns3 installation source link? https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation#Installation

Comment: thanks for your response a4arshad , yes I followed all the steps in that installation source link but still have the same problem

Comment: since you have not provided any information related to error. It is hard to guess. However, you can try these commands in a sequence. 1) ./waf clean 2) ./waf --disable-python configure 3) ./waf
I hope this might solve the problem.

Comment: I just changed the version of ns from 3.25 to 3.30, and it's working now, I don't know what was the problem but fine now the build is successful, thank you for your help :) :)